# No browser launches - Selenium Webdriver - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the very simple below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ECC.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
        WebDriver x = new ChromeDriver();
        x.get("www.google.com");
```

This throws:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:139)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:167)
     at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:124)
     at com.axletrees.tests.draft.In_Dev_Tests_Jorge.verifyLoginAD(In_Dev_Tests_Jorge.java:24)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
     at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonElement 
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
     ... 35 more
```

Any idea?

Comment: 1) What is ECC in your code and 2) Your URL should start with https:// www.google.com

Comment: Refer  http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/155js34ng7/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-gson-jsonelement

Comment: Please format your exception as code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by updating TestNG through eclipse marketplace. I had the latest build specified in the pom.xml file, and I didn't updated the TestNG manually in eclipse.

For the record if anyone faces the same problem, when going to the marketplace to see the installed apps, sometimes it does not gives the possibility of updating the app, it only says "installed"; to see if there are any updates, click in the "installed"  button and there you will see the option.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your Question:

1. You need to provide the full path of the cromedriver as below:

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ECC.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH+"cromedriver.exe");`

2. You need to provide the protocol to call the webpage: 
   `WebDriver x = new ChromeDriver(); x.get("http:\\google.com");`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. The ECC.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH had already specified the .exe also included. The problem was that I was using an old version of the selenium driver. Anyways, thanks again